# create dynamic price range slider in java

Tags: javascript

I want to create a dynamic Price range slider somthing like makemytrip.com. 
which will have min and max price value based on product price e.g the lowest product price is $50 and the highest is $200, can the available range in the slider start with $50 and end with $200?

Comment: You tried something for that?

Comment: Is this Java or JavaScript?  The two are very different languages.  If a web page, you almost certainly want JavaScript.

Comment: sounds like you are looking for javascript option neha, I removed java tag, retag if I was wrong

Answer (score 0):

Use [jQuery slider](http://jqueryui.com/slider/#range) to achieve this functionality. Demo available [here](http://jqueryui.com/slider/#range)

You will have to use the following code for this

```
 $(function () {
   $("#slider-range").slider({
     range: true,
     min: 50,
     max: 200,
     values: [50, 200],
     slide: function (event, ui) {
       $("#amount").val("$" + ui.values[0] + " - $" + ui.values[1]);
     }
   });
   $("#amount").val("$" + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 0) +
     " - $" + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 1));
 });
```

After creating the slider, you can change the slider min and max values as follows

```
$( "#slider-range" ).slider( "option", "max", 60 );
$( "#slider-range" ).slider( "option", "min", 300 );
```

Comment: Updated my answer. Please check